# image of open and closed set through continuous function between different metric spaces

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

$(X,d)$ and $(Y,\delta)$ metric spaces, $f:X\rightarrow Y$ continuous. I have to prove that:

$$(a)\;C\subseteq X \;\text{closed}\not \Rightarrow f(C)\subseteq Y \;\text{closed}$$

$$(b)\;A\subseteq X \;\text{open}\not \Rightarrow f(A)\subseteq Y \;\text{open}$$

I tried to write definitions of continuous function, open and closed set but I can't prove it. Help?

Comment: I think you are a bit confused. Either $f: \Bbb{R} \longrightarrow \Bbb{R}$ or $f(C) \subset Y$, if $Y \neq \Bbb{R}$.

Comment: You *have* to give an example to refute an implication. No avoiding it..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint**

(a) Take $f(x)=\sin(x)$ and $C$ closed set that contain $[0,2\pi]$.

(b) Take $f(x)=0$ and $A$ being any open set but the emptyset.